# Could a .ts file contain multiple classes

Tags: angular5

I want to create a `.ts` file which should contain my data model. Each data model maps to a `JSON` I'll either send or receive from the server. For eg. for user profile, the Json is

```
 {
  "firstname" : "d",
  "lastname" : "d",
  "email" : "dd",
  "password" : "d"
}
```

For above, I want to create a class as follows

```
export class UserProfile {

  constructor (public firstname:string,
               public lastname:string,
               public email:string,
               public password:string){}
}
```

Another JSON which the server might send is

```
{
result:"success"
addition-info:"something"
}
```

The class for above is

```
export class Result{

  constructor (public result:string,
               public additionalInfo:string){}
}
```

Is there a best practice in Angular on how to create files for data models. Could I create a single `.ts` file say `BackendApiModels.ts` which should store all the classes or shall I create one `.ts` file for each data model? I don't even know if it is possible to create a `.ts` file which can contain multiple classes, eg

BackendApi.ts

```
 export class UserProfile {

      constructor (public firstname:string,
                   public lastname:string,
                   public email:string,
                   public password:string){}
    }

    export class Result{

      constructor (public result:string,
                   public additionalInfo:string){}
    }
```

Is is possible to create a file like above in Angular (multiple classes and the name of the classes do not match the filename)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is entirely possible and valid to export several model classes or interfaces from the same .ts file...

```ts
export class Attachment {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(attachment) {
    this.id = attachment.id;
    this.name = attachment.name;
  }
}

export class Permissions {
  draftable: boolean;
  completable: boolean;

  constructor(perms) {
    this.draftable = perms.draftable;
    this.completable = perms.completable;
  }
}
```

Comment: Models that has an exclusive relationship should be kept together, while models that are shared should be kept separate.